# JavaScript parse text containing name value pairs

Tags: javascript, json, regex, parsing

I have some text string which is like a JSON string, but not an exact one. It is like below

```
First Name: John
Last name : Doe
Address :London
```

It will be better if an object can be extracted from this string, so that I can iterate over its properties (First Name, Address etc.) with for...in loop.

Any idea about how this can be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you change the way it gets outputted?

Comment: "*text string which is almost like a JSON string, but not an exact one*" I'd say that it aslmost has nothing in common with JSON. It has a `:` and that's basically where the similarity starts and ends.

Comment: Show the code so can help you out. As you asked "text string" First Name: John
Last name : Doe
Address :London 
How it's in variable?

Comment: Can you share more details? This looks a bit hard to parse if their either space in front / after the double colon or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make use of [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) (once, to extract each line into separate item, then once again, to separate property names from values):

```js
const str = `First Name: John
Last name : Doe
Address :London`,

      result = str
        .split("\n")
        .reduce((acc, substr) => {
          const [prop, value] = substr.split(/\s*:\s*/)
          acc[prop] = value
          return acc
        }, {})
        
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```